# Why is there no memory usage on two worker nodes in Spark, even though they are shown as running?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am utilizing a Spark Cluster with `pyspark` in Docker Swarm with three workers. One worker is on the same machine as the master, and the other two are located in other machines. I am using `sparkContext.addPyFile(file)` to add a python file and run functions from it.

app.py:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

SparkContext.setSystemProperty('spark.executor.memory', '20g')

sc = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName('test2') \
    .getOrCreate()

sc.sparkContext.addPyFile('test.py')

import test
train = test.build_model('file.csv')
```

Simplified model.py:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import ensemble
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
def build_model(file):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
        y = encoder.fit_transform(df['y'])
        count_vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word')
        x = count_vect.fit_transform(df['x'])
        model = ensemble.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, verbose=10, n_jobs=1, max_depth=1000)
        model.fit(x, y)
```

This is the Spark Master UI in port 8080 when I run the container with the app.py:

[image]

This is the UI in 4040 port:
[image]

Executors tab:
[image]

This is `htop` result in Spark Master machine:
[image]
As we can see, there is memory being used.

However, the result of `htop` in the other two worker machines doesn't show any memory usage. This leads me to believe that the other two workers are not being utilized, even though they show as if they're being used in the Spark Master UI.

Why is this happening? Is it because I'm running pure Python code, and not using the `sc.parallelize()` function from pyspark?